# How To Get The Data Out, Inside if/else Statement in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, if-statement, view, viewcontroller

I have two pickerViews in `ViewController` and a `Struct` where I made a function which will get data of PickerViews. In `didSelectRow` func of `PickerView` I wrote the below code.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView == fromPickerViewRolled {
            let optionArray1 = currencyManager.currencyArrayOption1[row]
        }
        else if pickerView == toPickerViewRolled {
    
            let optionArray2 = currencyManager.currencyArrayOption2[row]   
        }
    }
```

How may I get the data of `optionArray1` and ..Array2 outside of if/else so that I can use in function. Any help would be appreciated. Looking forward for an answer.

Comment: Can you show how you want to use it?

Comment: Do you have more than 2 picker views? If not you could use a ternary operator, `let optionArray = pickerView == fromPickerViewRolled ? currencyManager.currencyArrayOption1[row] : currencyManager.currencyArrayOption2[row]` and then use `optionArray` in the rest of the code in the function

Comment: I have two picker views only, could you please write in a code format  like I did.

Comment: Just replace your if/else with my code

Answer (score 0):

You just can declare an array outside the if statement block. Like this :

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    var currencyArray: [YourType] = []
    if pickerView == fromPickerViewRolled {
        currencyArray = currencyManager.currencyArrayOption1[row]
    }
    else if pickerView == toPickerViewRolled {
        currencyArray = currencyManager.currencyArrayOption2[row]
    }
    dump(currencyArray)
}
```

Comment: I am making an app which has 2 picker views, they have 2 arrays both with currencies, I have two arrays with currency, after getting the input from picker views when I pass the value to getFun(currency1: currencyArray, currency2: currencyArray), when I print the URL it give s me same value for eg: EUR_EUR. Could you pls help how to get the value separately so that I can use in url string like this https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=USD_INR&compact=ultra&apiKey=APIKEY

Comment: Your comment is not related to your question. Please ask a new one if needed. Validate this one if answer your question